# Debug go program result in "Too many goroutines, only loaded 1024"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am debugging a big go project and it has a lot of goroutines, when I hit breakpoints, the console will show this line:
`Too many goroutines, only loaded 1024`

and, if the goroutine hit the breakpoint is in the first 1024 listed goroutines, then the debug works fine, but if the paused goroutine not in the listed first 1024 goroutines, the the debug can't work, I can't see local variable value.

my question is, how to increase the 1024 limit?